# Vuejs2 Modal with route in vue-router

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to create a route with a modal and when you access with router-link to this router-path appears a modal above the current page or if i access directly from url appears the index with modal above.

For example: I'm in http://localhost/profile/1 and click in the sidebar Create team the url changes to http://localhost/team/create but the page behind the modal still is http://localhost/profile/1.

This is the code i'm trying:

router:

```
Vue.component('modal', Modal);    
export default new Router({
      mode: 'history',
      routes: [
       {
        path: '/',
        name: 'Hello',
        component: require('@/components/Hello'),
        meta: { auth: false }
      },

      {
        path: '/team',
        name: 'team',
        component: require('@/components/team/Index'),
        meta: { auth: true },
      },
      {
        path: '/team/create',
        name: 'CreateTeam',
        components: {
          b: CreateTeam
        },
        meta: { auth: true }
      },  
      ]
    })
```

App.vue

```
<template>

  <router-view></router-view>
  <!-- This is the "MODAL" router-view -->
  <router-view name="b"></router-view>              

</template>
```

Modal.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="modal">

      <slot name="body"></slot>  
        <button type="button" @click="$emit('close')">×</button>
   </div>
</template>
```

CreateTeam.vue

```
<template>
    <modal @close="vm.$router.go(-1)">

        <div slot="body" class="col-md-12">
        <!-- Form here -->
        </div>

    </modal>
</template>
```

Everything is working instead that when i go to /create/team behind the modal is empty

Comment: Your modal shouldn't be a route in this case, it should be an element of the same component that houses your `router-view`. When you need to show it, trigger it from that component using an event or state management or even passing a function through the `router-view` to to the components that need to trigger it.

Comment: I understand, but in this case i want to open in any component like a "global modal". If i do like you say all the components will have to have the code of the modal component and diferents paths ex: profile/modal, team/modal" I want to open team/create from anywhere

Comment: No, that's not what I'm saying. It should live in App.vue, it should not be a route, and your components that *are* routes should trigger it.

Comment: Oh ok, but how i change the route, ? Javascript directly?

Comment: sure. All components have access to `$router`.

Comment: If you want to have the back button working correctly and closing the modal, then a solution with router is preferable and would be more "clean"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If anyone needs this solution, i solved this way:

I created a component create-team Vue.component('create-team',CreateTeam) and i put it in the App.vue like this:

```
<create-team v-if="CreateTeam"></create-team>
```

In the same App.vue i created a computed with a vuex getter:

```
computed: {

    CreateTeam() {
         return store.getters.createTeam
    }
  },
```

In Sidebar i created a link like this:

```
 <a @click="CreateTeam" class="user-panel-action-link" href="/create/team">
   <i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i> Crear Equipo
 </a>
```

And a method CreateTeam

```
CreateTeam(e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      store.commit('setTeamModal')
      history.pushState('', 'Title of page', '/create/team');

    }
```

The store.js vuex is simple:

```
const state = {

    createTeam: false,
}

const mutations = {

    setTeamModal (state) {
      state.createTeam= true
    },
    deleteTeamModal (state) {
      state.createTeam= false
    }
}

const actions = {
    setTeamModal: ({ commit }) => commit('setTeamModal')
   deleteTeamModal: ({ commit }) => commit('setTeamModal')
}

const getters = {

    createTeam: state => state.createTeam
}

export default new Vuex.Store({
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations
})
```

And the last thing is in the CreateTeam.vue component the Close method i made somthing like this:

```
 Close() {
      this.$store.commit('deleteTeamModal')
      this.$router.go(-1)
    }

  }
```

Maybe someone can make it better, that's my little piece of help

Greetings

Comment: nice one! will give that a try, too - good to know `history.pushState(..)` works just with vue-router just like that..

Comment: I think using js to handle routing is not a good idea. there must be a way using vue-router patterns...

Answer (score 3):

If somebody else search for solution for similar problem nice one is presented [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/703#issuecomment-428123334).
Before redirect to modal route programmatically change components of named routes. Worked  for me like a charm with Login/Signup modals.
My notes:
1. Make sure modal routes are not child of any route (I had some problems with default route component).
2. Consider to add `router.back()` on modal close button.

```
router.js
    ...
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home,
      meta: {
        twModalView: true
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/directAccess',
      name: 'directAccess',
      component: DirectAccess
    },
    ...
    {
      path: '/:userId/tweet/:id',
      name: 'userTweet',
      beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
        const twModalView = from.matched.some(view => view.meta && view.meta.twModalView)

        if (!twModalView) {
          //
          // For direct access
          //
          to.matched[0].components = {
            default: TweetSingle,
            modal: false
          }
        }

        if (twModalView) {
          //
          // For twModalView access
          //
          if (from.matched.length > 1) {
            const childrenView = from.matched.slice(1, from.matched.length)
            for (let view of childrenView) {
              to.matched.push(view)
            }
          }
          if (to.matched[0].components) {
            to.matched[0].components.default = from.matched[0].components.default
            to.matched[0].components.modal = TweetModal
          }
        }

        next()
      }
    },
    ...
```