# Open a modal on Vue.js route change

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

Currently, my `vue-router` configuration looks like this:

```
export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home,
    },
    {
      path: '/settings',
      name: 'settings',
      component: Settings,
    }
  ],
});
```

Now, I want to define a new path, say `/some-modal-path`, on navigation to which, a modal, say`ModalComponent`, will open as an overlay above the current component.

Is this possible to be done with `vue-router`? If yes, how can it be done?

Comment: why not do it in `ModalComponent`'s mounted event ?

Comment: @JacobGoh I do not want the `ModalComponent` to be mounted until that particular route is opened

Comment: the mounted event for the component of path `/some-modal-path` ?

Comment: else, see `Per-Route Guard` in https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44598156/vuejs2-modal-with-route-in-vue-router?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: basically vue-router cant do that you need to add named router-view to the main route

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fast solution

Put `<router-view>` in each component

```
export default new Router({
      routes: [
        {
          path: '/',
          name: 'home',
          component: Home,
          children: [
            {   path: '/some-modal-path',
                component: ModalComponent,
                name: 'ModalComponent'
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          path: '/settings',
          name: 'settings',
          component: Settings,
          children: [
            {   path: '/some-modal-path',
                component: ModalComponent,
                name: 'ModalComponent'
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
    });
```

Comment: as much as i love the simplicity of this i had to ask, is there no better way to open this, in my case its a login modal and needs to be openable from each page

Comment: I get similar question, but the modal component is decided by logics (dynamically), I don't know how to mount dynamic page component to bootstrap-vue modal port.